# Django how to edit data for multiple objects at once

Tags: django

I created two models in django. First is about products (name, price etc) and second is shop which contains this products.
How can I edit every product from my shop in one form?

For example i have page with shop detail (all products, prices) and I want on this page edit few prices of products from this shop. I don't want click on every product and edit it, I want do it on one page. Is it possible? What is the best way to do it?

Comment: See: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/intro/tutorial07/#adding-related-objects

Answer (score 2):

You can use [inline forms](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/intro/tutorial07/#adding-related-objects)

```
# admin.py
class ProductInline(admin.StackedInline):
    model = Product

class StoreAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [ProductInline]

admin.site.register(Store, StoreAdmin)
```

With this configuration, you will be able to edit / add / delete related *Products* on the *Store* admin page.

Comment: Apparently he wants any user to be able to do this

Answer (score 1):

**Solution 1**
The [Django admin site](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/contrib/admin/), acessible at `http://<myurl>:<myport>/admin/`, will allow you do edit saved model data. Can't remember off the top of my head if you can edit multiples or not though..

**Solution 2**
Connect to your datasource using a SQL Editor for example, using MySQLWorkbench, and script it, which would allow you to update all the products for one shop in one fell swoop. Some example SQL would be `update products set price='4.99' where shop_id=1` or something similar

Comment: Hi, thank you! Is it possible to do it not in django admin? For example i create shop and i add to this shop 10 products and every user can on website change his prices in shop detail page.

Comment: You want to allow every user to be able to change prices?

Comment: For example i create shop to my user and I choose products. User can only edit products prices but he must have possibility to do it on one page. For example he open his shop detail and he can edit all prices on this one page.

Comment: I'd just use a for loop in the template then and pass in all the models or use multiple model forms